# Are elliptical orbits always symmetrical to the spin axis of the planet?

Tags: orbital-motion

It seems that because hyperbolic orbits are not always symmetrical to the spin axis of the planet or star, the same might be true of elliptical orbits. Is it right that circular orbits are always symmetrical in this way, and the greater the eccentricity of an elliptical orbit, the more the possibility of asymmetry? Thank you.

Comment: Is the question if orbital and spin angular momentum are parallel? Then the answer is: Not necessarily.

Comment: What does "symmetrical to the spin axis" mean?

Comment: Alternatively, one might say, symmetrical to the equator line. So the incoming and outgoing angles to the equator are the same.

Comment: Can you provide an example of an orbit that is not symmetrical to the equator?

Comment: Hyperbolic orbits are sometimes asymmetrical to the equator. The incoming angle is sometimes different from the outgoing one. In papers on the flyby anomaly, this was an issue, and it's certainly the case.

Comment: A "symmetry" is a mathematical transformation of a thing that leaves the thing unchanged.  For example, if you have a drawing that looks the same as its mirror image, then that drawing has a reflective symmetry.  I think maybe "symmetrical" is not the word that you are looking for.  It sounds maybe like you are asking about whether a planet's axis of rotation is parallel to some axis of the orbit.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see your comment. I was about to say 'well, you may be right that symmetry is the wrong word to use'. But NASA use it in the situation - from the paper I've linked to in a comment below: "FIG. 1. Equatorial view of the NEAR flyby, the most asymmetrical flyby with respect to the Equator and the flyby with the
largest energy change." So it seems to be a kind of symmetry in three dimensions, which is how I saw it - any orbit has reflection symmetry through a line through the foci. And the equator has symmetry. The question may be about whether the two can be related in some way.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that objects in circular orbit must have a spin angular momentum vector which is parallel with the orbital angular momentum vector. The spin of the object could be in any arbitrary direction. It is only roughly true that planets in our solar system tend to have their spin axis direction aligned with their orbital axis direction. All planets orbit counter-clockwise (looking down from the north pole) while most planets also spin counter-clockwise in roughly the same plane. However, all planets' spin have tilt. The Earth's spin axis has a tilt of about 24 degrees which gives us our seasons. Uranus is tilted almost completely sideways (90 degrees). And Venus even rotates in a clock-wise direction, so its spin axis is anti-parallel to its orbital axis. There is no correlation, as far as I am aware, between the eccentricity of an orbit and that object's spin axis. If there was such a correlation, it would probably be simply incidental.

Comment: I'll make the question clearer. Let's take the Earth as the planet, and look at the orbits of

Comment: ...and look at the orbits of space probes. There's no ecliptic plane with this situation. The question is about the geometry of different kinds of orbits. What kinds of orbits are always symmetrical to the planet's spin axis, and what kind can be asymmetrical? I know hyperbolic orbits can be asymmetrical. It seems that elliptical orbits can too, and the further form circular they go, the more the possibility of asymmetry. Circular orbits, on the other hand, probably have to be symmetrical to the spin axis of the planet. Is that right?

Comment: Can you draw a picture to go with the question?

Comment: No, as I said, the spin and orbit are separate things. You can certainly have circular orbits around earth that do not align with the spin of the Earth. There's no reason to expect that all circular orbits around the Earth are along the equator.

Comment: I didn't mean along the equator, nor ever wrote anything like that. Tom, here's the drawing:

Comment: it doesn't paste in. Will try to find a NASA paper with a diagram, I think there is one.

Comment: Yes, below the abstract here

Comment: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.100.091102    there are 3 diagrams, click on the left one, it gives some idea.

Comment: The picture helped. I still don't know how to define "asymmetric to the equator" but I know it when I see it.

Comment: The drawing I wanted to post showed a straight line, the equator, with a curved line crossing it. The incoming angle is different from the outgoing angle, because the orbit is set in three dimensions in a way that is not symmetrical to the equator. The question was about whether elliptical orbits can do that as well, and it seems that if a hyperbolic orbit can, then an elliptical can as well, particularly a very eccentric one. But I think the special case of a circular orbit has to be symmetrical to the equator. So the greater the eccentricity, the more asymmetry is possible? Thank you.

Comment: Ah! So, symmetrical means perigee is over the equator?!

Comment: Symmetrical means, as in NASA's use of the word, with what they call the 'incoming angle' equal to the outgoing angle. Those are angles to the equator. It might mean with perigee over the equator, as you say. An elliptical orbit can certainly by symmetrical in this way, and it seems to me that since a hyperbolic one can be asymmetrical, so can an eccentric elliptical orbit. But when I picture a circular orbit, it seems that the angles to the equator are always equal. Can anyone shed any light on that?

Comment: I don't think this definition of "symmetrical" makes sense for bound orbits. The 'incoming angle' and 'outgoing angle' are defined as angles measured from "infinity" aren't they? A bound orbit doesn't come or go to infinity, so how do you measure this angle?

Comment: I see what you mean. But hyperbolic orbits make a curved path near the mass, this is why it's a bit unclear what is meant by the 'incoming angle' - perhaps the angle to the equator as it crosses it. But since both hyperbolic and elliptical orbits make a curved path, it seems possible that both can be asymmetrical in the same way. The reason it seems so is really the PLANE of the orbit. A very eccentric elliptical orbit is like a hyperbolic orbit - who cares whether the lines join or not at a very large distance. Both orbits can have the same sort of plane, so it seems both can be asymmetrical.

Comment: It matters a lot whether the orbit is bound or unbound. An unbound orbit has "at infinity" in two different directions. A bound orbit doesn't have an "at infinity" and even if you stretched an elliptical orbit to be infinitely elongated, it's "at infinity" would come from one direction and you can't measure an angle there...

Comment: Near the mass is where NASA assesses the angles. They're local, nothing to do with the angles of the asymptote lines. From a point of view near the mass, an elliptical orbit goes off in two directions, just as a hyperbolic orbit does. In both cases, two lines go curving off from near the mass, and in both cases, there's a plane that can be symmetrical to the equator, or not. Whether the lines straighten while heading towards infinity, or curve round and join at a large distance away, makes no difference in relation to this question. Can anyone support this or give reason to think otherwise?

Comment: Can you give a clear definition of how each angle is measured then? You need 3 points to measure an angle.

Comment: Perhaps you can find something here: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.100.091102

Comment: There's no mention of angles or the symmetries you are talking about in the abstract. Asking me to read a research paper to answer a stack overflow question is probably asking a bit much.

Comment: I'm hoping to find someone who knows this area already. NASA use the angles in a formula they published, so it's on the map in some sense. They describe the angles as 'The formula can be expressed in its simplest form in terms of the respective declinations i and o of the incoming and outgoing osculating asymptotic velocity vectors'. Perhaps I should contact someone there, but that probably defines it better than I have so far. Thank you for your help.